# Pure CSS Modal & Popup without href

Tags: html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a modal popup made purely out of CSS only. I don't even need any animations, but I'd like it to have a semi-transparent full screen white background blocking the page. I've found a few just searching, but the problem is that they use href tags to open and close the popup window. So the problem is that when you click on the links, the page moves to that href tag.

I found one here http: //codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg but like I said, it uses href tags so the page moves to that href tag. I'm using these on long pages with much content, so I need the page to stay in the same spot when it's used.

Maybe there's a way to use label and IDs instead of 'a hrefs'?

I really could use the help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you include the code of what you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of CSS and a checkbox-hack as described here: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ with an overlay demo shown here: http://codepen.io/Idered/pen/vytkH

As stated in the article and show in the demo you are able to hide a checkbox, attach a label referencing the checkbox id as `for`. Then on clicks show an overlay, which is otherwise not displayed. Adding on to that, you are also to add transitions to fade the modal/overlay in/out.

Example of CSS to make it work:

```
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}    

.modal-state {
  display: none;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="btn" for="modal-1">Show me modal with a cat</label>
<input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
<div class="modal">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that worked exactly how I wanted it.
I just added another <label class="btn" for modal-1"> inside the modal div as the close button.

I would upvote your answer if I had enough points.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's currently possible.

Pure CSS modal uses `:target` as a trick to react to the click, since CSS doesn't have events.

I don't know any other tricks you can use to substitute `:target`.

Maybe could try to make the modal fixed when not `:target`, so when the user clicks, it won't scroll. I tried to do it, but my skills in CSS is limited and I tried for less than 5 min. I'm not sure it will work, tho.

Answer (score 0):

*There is* actually a CSS trick for building a gallery without href. The problem is that in my opinion is not elegant and requires hidden radioboxes.

- Article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked#Using_hidden_radioboxes_in_order_to_store_some_CSS_boolean_values
- Demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/6268/=css-checked-gallery.zip

But I would definitely opt for the "href way" – or at least that's what I did when I wrote [my own pure-CSS slide renderer](https://madmurphy.github.io/takefive.css/)…

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible.  CSS isn't a reactive language, unlike javascript, which can handle events from user input.  The CSS-only solutions that you've found navigate away from the page so that the page can show the modal on load.

The CSS-only solution you linked is very clever, and it's about as close as you can hope to get.  Sorry!

Comment: As other have shown, you can use a hidden radio button, this is post is inaccurate.